# Send service result to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've got a `BroadcastReceiver` which checks if Internet connection is available then it starts a service which retrieves an `ArrayList` from the DB:

```
public class NetworkWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        Intent retrieveVehicleList = new Intent(context, RetrieveVehicleListService.class);

        if (info != null)
        {
            if (info.isConnected())
            {
                context.startService(retrieveVehicleList);
            }
            else
            {
                context.stopService(retrieveVehicleList);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class RetrieveVehicleListService extends IntentService
{
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles;

    private void parseVehiclesFromMap(ArrayList vehicles)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++)
        {
            final Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
            HashMap vehicleMap = (HashMap) vehicles.get(i);

            v.setPlate(vehicleMap.get("plate").toString());
            v.setKm(vehicleMap.get("km") == null ? null : Integer.parseInt(vehicleMap.get("km").toString()));
            v.setFuelQuantity(Double.parseDouble(vehicleMap.get("fuel_quantity").toString()));
            v.setEffectiveFuelEconomy(Double.parseDouble(vehicleMap.get("fuel_economy").toString()));
            v.setInsuranceDate(vehicleMap.get("insurance_date") == null ? null : new LocalDate(vehicleMap.get("insurance_date").toString()));
            v.setMatriculationDate(new LocalDate(vehicleMap.get("matriculation_date").toString()));
            v.setLatitude(vehicleMap.get("latitude") == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(vehicleMap.get("latitude").toString()));
            v.setLongitude(vehicleMap.get("longitude") == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(vehicleMap.get("longitude").toString()));
            v.setFuelType(FuelType.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(vehicleMap.get("id_fuel").toString())));

            this.vehicles.add(v);
        }
    }

    private void sendRequest(int userID)
    {
        Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                try
                {
                    HashMap json = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, HashMap.class);
                    String errorCode = json.get("error_code").toString();

                    switch (errorCode)
                    {
                        case "0":
                            parseVehiclesFromMap((ArrayList) json.get("vehicles"));
                            break;
                        default:
                            // TODO gestire
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO gestire
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        VehicleListRequest request = new VehicleListRequest(String.valueOf(userID), listener, null);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(getString(clyky.cartracker.R.string.sharedPreferencesName), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int userID = sp.getInt("id_user", SplashActivity.DEFAULT_USER_ID);

        if (userID != SplashActivity.DEFAULT_USER_ID)
        {
            sendRequest(userID);
        }
    }

    public RetrieveVehicleListService()
    {
        super("RetrieveVehicleList");
        vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

I want my `MainActivity` gets that `ArrayList` from `RetrieveVehicleListService` when the activity is started. How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalBroadcast reciever to send data from service to activity. Add following code to your activty

```
private BroadcastReceiver  BReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //put here whaterver you want your activity to do with the intent received
ArrayList<String> arrayList=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("arrayList");

}           
};

protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter("message"));
}

protected void onPause (){
super.onPause();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
}
```

and use following method to send broadcast from service

```
private void sendBroadcast (boolean success){
Intent intent = new Intent ("message"); //put the same message as in the filter you used in the activity when registering the receiver
intent.putExtra("success", success);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayList", arrayList);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: does this work only when my activity is in foreground? because I want to retrieve data from the server indipendently from the state of my application

Comment: Yes you need to store data locally if activity is in background

Answer (score 0):

Use Local Broadcast Receiver :

send broadcast using below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent("YourAction");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle .putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)vehicles);
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",bundle);
intent.putExtras(intent)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And receive broadcast in your activity:

```
private MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver;

@Override
public void onResume(){
    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("YourAction");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    if(myReceiver != null)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    myReceiver = null;
}

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             // Here you have the received broadcast 
             // And if you added extras to the intent get them here too
             // this needs some null checks
         Intent intent = getIntent();
       Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
       ArrayList<Object> object = (ArrayList<Object>)args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");

        }
}
```

Comment: does this work even if the activity is in background?

Comment: Broadcast will receive when activity is in background as well.